# STLink cannot connect, unless VDD is connected

Tags: power-supply, stm32, st-link

I have made my own board with an stm32g474 on it. Unfortunately I have some problem with connecting to it with ST-link. The board has it's own power supply.
If I connect the SWDIO, SWCLK, NRST and GND pins , then the ST-link cannot connect to it. 
However it works, if I disconnect the board's power supply and connect the ST-link's 3,3V.

Do you have any idea, why is that?

Comment: For me, both boards power supply connected and ST-Link's Vdd pin connected to one of the MCU Vdd pins was the working combination. I think board needs its external power source, as far as I know, ST-Link shouldn't be able to power the board. Vdd pin in the ST-Link was some kind of a sense input for ST-Link. I don't have detailed knowledge, don't take my words granted.

Comment: The Vdd pin on an actual ST-link is a required target voltage detection *input* not an output.  But on the fakes and the discovery boards it is an optional output, those do not work with targets of substantially different I/O voltage.

Comment: I tried it with a Nucleo's ST-link and with a Chinese ST-link_V2.
It's the same with both of them.

Comment: I just connected The ST-link vdd to the board through a 10k resistor. It seems working.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the ST-Link can work with a range of different voltages, it needs the voltage reference what to use from the target. If it for example always used 3.3V, it would damage something if connected to a 2.7V target.

Comment: I just connected The ST-link vdd to the board through a 10k resistor. It seems working.

Comment: Nucleo has no level converter so it has 3.3V IO voltage even without connecting the supplies - but it must be configured to take power from correct input (STlink USB) so it has supply voltage. Otherwise the Nucleo ST-Link is unpowered, unless you give 3.3V from target. The real ST-Link dongle has level converter so it will require IO voltage supply from target.

Answer (score 1):

The ST link contains a **dual supply translating transceiver** to ensure signal level compatibility.
([74LVC8T245](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC_LVCH8T245.pdf) *this exact one*)

As you could have guessed from the dual supply part, the `Vdd_target` wire on the connector sources the secondary side `Vcc(b)` of the transceiver. Without supply, it doesn't work.

[image: 74LVC8T245]

*Powering it trough a 10k resistor is also not recommended.*

([bom](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html#resource), [other source](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkiNCSAZ/stlink-v2-at-18v))

Comment: Hmm. I dont really understand.
Many sites says that the vdd pin is not needed when the board has an external power supply.
I also doesn't understand why is it not working for me when the board power supply and the ST-link VDD pin is connected to the board.

Comment: Well which sites say that? Also it is not wise to blindly believe everything you read on the net. People might be wrong and they might not even know they are wrong.

Comment: You are right.
Still dont understand why is it not working when the board's supply is on and the ST-link's 3,3V pin is connected directly.

Comment: @Tardief If it works without Vdd you have a clone ST Link without this tranceiver.

Comment: No, it's not working without Vdd. Also not working with Vdd. It only works when the board supply is on and i connect the ST-link's Vdd with 10k resistor OR the boad supply is on and the board is supplied through the ST-link Vdd pin. 
Also it is a chinese V2.

Comment: @Tardief Yes of course both the ST Link and the target board need to be powered. The Vdd of the ST Link only provides level translation. The ST Link does not provide power.